# I need to use a if statement on a button click object within a timer tick?

Tags: c#, timer

Basically in the code below where i highlight, i would like to know how to use drawBricks method in the timer tick when that button(btnDisplayBricks) is pressed. Because i am using a timer tick and picturebox for paper drawings etc i cannot just simply call the method from within the button click event because the paper then clears in the timer only allowing me to display the bricks before timer1 starts any ideas.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);

        DrawBall();

        MoveBall();

        DrawBat(paper);

        if (btnDisplayBricks_Click[0] = true)               ///code here problem

        //then call method
            DrawBricks(paper);




    private void btnDisplayBricks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawBricks(paper);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Check lordkain's answer: The difference is that `=` is the assignment operator, where-as `==` is the equivalency operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem is in your equation, you should use == instead of =

```
if (btnDisplayBricks_Click[0] == true)
```

also move methodbtnDisplayBricks_Click outside of timer1_Tick

```
private bool buttonClicked = false;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
    DrawBall();
    MoveBall();
    DrawBat(paper);

    if (buttonClicked)
    {
        DrawBricks(paper);
        // maybe you want to set buttonclicked to false again, but specs are not clear to me
        // buttonClicked = false;
    }
}

private void btnDisplayBricks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawBricks(paper);
    buttonClicked = true;
}
```

Comment: getting this error with that equation      Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Comment: Is my assumption  right thatr btnDisplayBricks_Click is an event handler on click of button DisplayBricks?

Comment: yes that's correct, i want to use the button when the timer has started not before so that's why i need to check the condition before in the timer before  call method DrawBricks

Comment: oke, so you want to know if the button has been clicked. I will update my answer, please comment if this is what you want

Comment: yes that's correct then it will call my needed method thank you for your time by the way

Comment: magic thank you so much just out of interest what would setting the buttonClicked = false allow me to do? redraw the bricks using that same button?

Comment: setting the buttonClicked  to false again allows you to decide every time when method timer1_Tick is called if you want to call DrawBricks.